# I am getting an error message the says that they are expecting a ";"

Tags: php, html

I am using VS to write some PHP and I am getting an error message that is saying ';' expected. I have looked at the code and I do not see where I should have another one. The message is saying that they are expecting one for `<div class='text'>`, which makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain why I am getting this error message?

```
<?php
$db =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecom_store");
function getPro(){
    global $db;

    $get_products = "select * from products order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,8";
    $run_products = mysqli_query($db, $get_products);

    while($row_products=mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)){
        $pro_id = $row_products['product_id'];
        $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];
        $pro_price = $row_products['product_price'];
        $pro_img1 = $row_products['product_img1'];

        echo "
            <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 single'>
                <div class='product'>
                    <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_img1' class='img-responsive' ></a>

                    <div class='text'>
                        <h3><a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>$pro_title</a></h3>
                        <p class='price'>$ $pro_price</p>
                        <p class='buttons'>
                            <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' class='btn btn-default'>View Details</a>
                            <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i> Add to cart</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        ";
    }
}?>
```

[image]

Comment: No issue in code. Working fine

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, please?

Comment: I provided an image of the code but like @ShivendraSingh stated, the code appears to work fine. I just don't know why it has an error message.

Comment: Do you get an actual PHP error, or just a notice in your code editor?

Comment: @showdev The error is just in my editor.

Comment: Which editor? Maybe it doesn't understand multi-line strings or something.

Comment: Probably its an IDE issue, you should report the bug to them

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Editor 1.35.1. It sounds like the issue is with VS and not the code. I just wanted to make sure because it has been a while since I have worked with php so I wanted to make sure it was not a self induced ID-10-T error!